# Remove/hide compound node without removing/hiding descendants

Tags: cytoscape.js

In cytoscape.js, compoundNode.remove() removes the compound node and its descendants from the graph.

Is there a way to only remove the compound node and keep the descendants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `eles.move()` : http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/graph-manipulation/eles.move

Then you can remove (what used to be) the parent node.